# ReactJS - Array comparison, Render only if name exists in both arrays

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I am working on a Star Wars web app using ReactJS with data being pulled from the SWAPI (API for returning JSON data about star wars). I have everything working but would like more control over the results that are pulled. Currently **every** character is being pulled from SWAPI, I would like to specify which characters are displayed in my own JSON file and compare this with the results from Swapi.

Here is breakdown of tasks:

- Use Fetch to pull Star Wars Character information as JSON from SWAPI and to ApiResonse.props.results
- Add array of specified characters to App state.characters
- Compare names from App.state.Characters with ApiResponse.results and render list of characters

**Here is my current code:**

```
/* App */
class App extends React.Component {

    // Set initial state
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            characters: [],
        }   
    }

    // Add specified characters to App.state.characters
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState ({
            characters : require('./charnames')
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar/>
                <Header/>
                <Characters/>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**SWAPI Component**

```
// Uses react-fetch to retrive json from swapi
class Api extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <Fetch url="http://swapi.co/api/people/">
        <ApiResponse test={this.props.results}/>
      </Fetch>
    )
  }
}

class ApiResponse extends React.Component{
    render(){
        if (this.props.results) {
            return (
                {/* I believe my array comparison should occur here */}
                <div className="row">
                    {this.props.results.map((key) =>
                        <h1>{key.name}</h1>
                    )}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**App State**

```
Props Empty
State characters: Array[2]
 0: {name: "Luke Skywalker"}
 1: {name: "Han Solo"}
```

**Api Props**

```
Props results: array[10]
 0: {gender: "male", name="Luke Skywalker"}
 1: {gender: "male", name="Han Solo"}
 2: {gender: "female", name="Leia Organa"}
```

So with the results above "Lei Organa" would be omitted as she does not exist in the App State, I hope this question makes sense!

TL;DR - Compare 'names' from App.state.characters with ApiResponse.props.results

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have the correct idea, what you want to do is run a `filter` method against your API results that then matches against your application state.

I highly recommend attempting to write a basic filter yourself, an excellent tutorial can be found here:

http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/filtering-arrays-with-array-filter.html

Once you have done that leveraging something like lodash's `_.filter` method (https://lodash.com/docs#filter) will get the job done quickly and easily.

One last note, you could do the filtering in the render method of `ApiResponse`, however I would consider leveraging `componentWillReceiveProps` and doing the filter there, leave your render as dumb as possible.